# Dynamic list - Add Numbers Automatically

Tags: php

I have a db where I manually add data. Some of the fields are:

```
ID AA Name Percentage(will be changing once a week)

1   2.  Me     10%

2   1.  You    40%
```

When I call the db with my dynamic list I get all names sorted By Perentage. The AA column I need it in order to get this result:

```
1. You  40%
2. Me   10%
```

It's easy to manually play with AA column (since my entries are no more than 10-15) and match it with the Percentage so I get the correct display that I need.

But if my entries become e.g 30 it will be very difficult to change all the time the AA column to match with the Percentage one.

So is there any modification I can do to my dynamic_list.php so I get the
1.
2.
generated automaticaly? Here is my dynamic_list.php:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Category='Deksioseis' ORDER BY percentage DESC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
// count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
        $i=0;
            $dynamicListDeks = '<table id="pl_list" class="list">';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $id = $row["ID"];
                $aa = $row["AA"];
                $client_name = $row["Client_Name"];
                $short_name = $row["Short_Name"];
                $details = $row["Details"];
                $percent = $row["Percentage"];
        $dynamicListDeks .= ($i==0) ? '<tr>':'';
        $dynamicListDeks .= '<td class="lst_aa">
                        ' . $aa . '
                     </td>
                                     <td class="lst_l">
                        <img src="../rooms/' . $short_name  . '.png" alt="' . $client_name . '" />
                     </td>
                     <td class="lst_nam">
                        <a id="' . $short_name . '" name="' . $short_name . '" class="room">' . $client_name . '</a>
                                     </td>
                     <td class="lst_det">
                    ' . $details . '
                     </td>
                         <td class="lst_per">
                    ' . $percent . '%
                    <br />
                     </td>';
        $dynamicListDeks .= ($i==1) ? '</tr>':'';
        $i++;
        ($i==2) ? $i=0:'';
        }
        $dynamicListDeks .='</table>';
        } else {
            $dynamicListDeks = "";
            }
        mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a counter in your PHP code that you increment for each run of the loop:

```
$aa = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  $id = $row["ID"];
  $aa++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving AA in database you may add variable which will keep value of AA which u can display later.

```
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE Category='Deksioseis' ORDER BY percentage DESC");
        $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        // count the output amount
        if ($productCount > 0) {
        $i=0;
        $aa=0;

        $dynamicListDeks = '<table id="pl_list" class="list">';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $id = $row["ID"];
            $aa++;
            $client_name = $row["Client_Name"];
            $short_name = $row["Short_Name"];
            $details = $row["Details"];
            $percent = $row["Percentage"];
    $dynamicListDeks .= ($i==0) ? '<tr>':'';
    $dynamicListDeks .= '<td class="lst_aa">
                    ' . $aa . '
                 </td>
                                 <td class="lst_l">
                    <img src="../rooms/' . $short_name  . '.png" alt="' . $client_name . '" />
                 </td>
                 <td class="lst_nam">
                    <a id="' . $short_name . '" name="' . $short_name . '" class="room">' . $client_name . '</a>
                                 </td>
                 <td class="lst_det">
                ' . $details . '
                 </td>
                     <td class="lst_per">
                ' . $percent . '%
                <br />
                 </td>';
    $dynamicListDeks .= ($i==1) ? '</tr>':'';
    $i++;
    ($i==2) ? $i=0:'';
    }
    $dynamicListDeks .='</table>';
    } else {
        $dynamicListDeks = "";
        }
    mysql_close();
```

Comment: seems like my answer is the same and also older, but not accepted somehow?;)